# Python Beginner: ImportError when run from NP++ but not IDLE

Tags: python, notepad++, nppexec

I am using Python 3.3 (2.7 is also installed) and a compatible version of pygame. Recently I have been trying to switch from IDLE to Notepad++

I am using a saved shortcut in Notepad++

```
    C:\Python33\python.bat "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(FILE_NAME)"
```

which runs the batch file:

```
    @echo off

    cd %1
    %2

    if not errorlevel 1 goto quit
    echo.
    echo.
    pause
    :quit
```

When I run C:\Python33\Foldername\imp_prob.py

```
    import pygame
```

in IDLE it works fine, in Notepad++ using that shortcut it gives an ImportError: No module named pygame

My questions are:

1. Why is the NP++ method not producing the same result?
2. How can I change the shortcut or batch file to make it run stuff that IDLE can run?
3. What method can I use to ensure that I can import a module regardless of which directory I am running the program from?

edit: a working alternative was in the answers to [How do you run a python script from within notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392629/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-from-within-notepad)

I had some issues with the code they provided, but replacing "python" with the full path to my python33 install solved that.

I still don't understand why pygame wouldn't import when using my run shortcut. I also don't understand why NppExec works when Run doesn't.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392629/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-from-within-notepad ?

Comment: If `%2` by itself works, then i guess your `PATH` Python is used. Use full paths to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to set your systemvariables. Idle does not require these steps. You entered the full path to the python.exe in np++ to execute the python program, but the path to the modules etc. is still unknown.

Add the paths, and try again.

System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables, in the bottom window look for a "Path" variable, Edit and append the following the existing entries (do not delete anything in there!)

;C:\Python33;C:\Python33\DLLs;C:\Python33\Lib

for Python 3.3, if you have installed it into its default directory.

To see if everything worked, open the console anywhere (shift+rightclick -> Open Command Window Here) and just type "python". The python console should open, telling you that you use python 3.3. You then also do not need to tell np++ the full python path, but instead can just use "python" again.