# Python, instant closing in a simple code

Tags: python

I have written these lines in python and ran it. But the result appears only for a second then it closes itself. What can i do to prevent it from closing?

```
   print("Enter your name:")
   x = input()
   print("Hello, " + x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Windows from closing Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22436864/stop-windows-from-closing-python)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.

You can run your code in console/command line/idle so that the parent process does not quit.

Or more programmatically, you can put `input()` at the end.

```
print("Enter your name:")
x = input()
print("Hello, " + x)
input() # better with a friendly note
```

If I recall correctly, `input` has platform dependent behavior handling signals/interrupts, but generally you can type `<enter>`, `<Ctrl+C>`, or `<EOF>` to end the program.