# Relative path for Python with Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I am using:
Notepad++, Python 3.4, Windows 7

I've got the following problem:
If I want (for example) to open a file. I always have to put in the whole path for example
"C:\Python34\05_Python_Project\Python_von_Kopf__\chapter7\webapp-chapter7\cgi-bin\some_file.txt"

I want to a write just a short filename like:

```
with open ('some_file.txt') as footer_d:
    ...
```

I realise that Notepad++ is searching in the following path:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++"

Can I somehow change/ configure Notepad++ for searching at the file location???

Comment: Please use english when posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you need to use german language then have a look at [www.python-forum.de](https://www.python-forum.de).

Comment: changed it to English language... my English is unvortunatelly not this good. But hope you can figure it out (the question might not be to difficult). Dan

Comment: Hmm.  Your English is fine.  It's better than my German, and I have been working in a German speaking office for the last eight months!

Comment: How are you running the script?  If you are using nppexec, you can change the directory when the script is run.

Comment: I use "run" -> "run external programm" (F5) in Notepad ++
In addition i did write the following in the line:
(I read this in the internet)
- cmd /k "C:\Python34\python.exe $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
- the /k has as a advantage that the cmd-window stays open

Thank you (not using it too often...my English... just for scripting)

Comment: I think you have to copy the lessons from your book to a working directory e.g. D:\python-scripts and please go deeper into nppexec for running python from Notepad++. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392629/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-from-within-notepad
and [Running Python Programs from Notepad++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJipYE1JT38)

Comment: I did paste it in German first and did translate it to English afterward... (just hit the "Enter-key"... in between... sorry)

Comment: Ok, I have the NppExec installed... but I guess I am not using it correctly at the moment. Thank you for your answers!
I will try to get into the "NppExec"-Tool...
(Unvortunatelly there is no Youtube-Movie" ;-) )
Oh, I realised, I do not have the "NppExec" --> I will install it -> Thanks!

Comment: Please note the YouTube link in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to implement this, is to do it all in Python:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:/Python34/05_Python_Project/Python_von_Kopf__/chapter7/webapp-chapter7/cgi-bin")
```

(The Windows API is quite happy with forward slashes as a path separator.  It's command line applications that tend not to like them.)  Alternatively:

```
dirlist = ["C:\\", "Python34", "05_Python_Project", Python_von_Kopf__",
           "chapter7", "webapp-chapter7", "cgi-bin"]
dir = os.path.join(*dirlist)
os.chdir(dir)
```